# Unity Project is locked at 75 fps instead of 80 fps Oculus VR

Tags: unity-game-engine, frame-rate, virtual-reality, oculus

All my unity projects are locked at 75 fps instead of 80. Tried to find the cause no avail for weeks. The performance headroom in the OVR Debugger is at around 70% so I still have a lot to work with. Even on empty scenes, everything is locked at 75 fps. Any Help? Also, Oculus can't log in on the oculus forms so that's why I'm asking here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Check yout vsync settings (`Quality settings`, `Other` group)
2. Find mentions of `Application.targetFrameRate` in your code
3. What is your display FPS? Your framerate counter is probably about display and not HMD
4. Each Oculus model [has it's own target framerate](https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/unity/unity-perf/), what is yours?

Comment: Oculus overrides all settings related to vsync, and target frame so trying to change anything either manually or FROM script doesn't matter. Mine is a rift s which is supposed to run at 80. I am using the default debugging tool provided by Oculus. One thing that I found is that the app inherents the vsync from my monitor for some reason if I set it to 60fps (normally have it at 75) my unity apps will run at 60 :/ I can't find a reason for that. Other Unity apps like BeatSaber run at 80.

Comment: What unity version are you using? They have new XR module in 2019.3, also there are different render settings, one of them, if I remember correctly, renders one picture to HMD and monitor

Answer (score 0):

To clarify is a bug within Unity and that spreads around different versions even 2019.3. If you have this notorious bug, disable vsync within the quality settings. Took me ages to figure it out, so I hope this might help someone.